# Audio play with object tag

Tags: javascript, dom, html4

I need to use only `HTML4` and not deprecated elements or attributes to play some tracks I've made in a website for a project. My code is :

```
function play_track( track )
{
  // Choose the track
  if ( track == 0 ) track = "backtrack_1" ; else track = "backtrack_2" ;
    var exists = document.getElementById ( "backtrack" );
    var body             = document.getElementById( "game_body" );

    // Does the node already exists?
    if ( exists )
    {
       // Than delete the node
       exists = body.removeChild ( exists );
       exists = null;
    }       
    // Create or recreate the node
    exists = document.createElement ( "object" );
    exists.setAttribute ( "id", "backtrack" );
    exists.setAttribute ( "data", "Media/audio/" + track + ".wav" ) ;   
    body.appendChild ( exists ) ;
    set_element_style ( "backtrack", "absolute", 1, 1, 1, 1, -5 ) ;
    exists.style.visibility = "hidden" ;

    return ;
}
```

With this code, calling the function the first time the backtrack_1 starts but every time I recall the function it creates another node with the new track selected without erasing the first. So every time I have more than one track playing. What's wrong with my code? With alerts I know that "exists = null" it's executed every time.

Comment: Trying to do audio on the WWW using only HTML 4 features is a highly unreasonable constraint to try to operate under.

Comment: I know but i have no choice : the project rules allow me only tu use HTML4 not deprecated elements or attributes. It's useless i know but i must follow those rules or i will not pass the exam.